# How long does it take to register a feature in azure?

Tags: azure

I just enabled [OIDCIssuerPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#register-the-enableoidcissuerpreview-feature-flag) feature flag in azure with this command.

```
$ az feature register --name EnableOIDCIssuerPreview --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService
```

Now when I check it with the below command I've got status `Registering`.

```
$ az feature list -o table --query "[?contains(name, 'Microsoft.ContainerService/EnableOIDCIssuerPreview')].{Name:name,State:properties.state}"
Name                                                State
--------------------------------------------------  -----------
Microsoft.ContainerService/EnableOIDCIssuerPreview  Registering
```

How long does it take to register a feature in azure ?

Answer (score 3):

It took around 15 minutes for me. I don't exclude that it might take even longer!